# Cooking file mode to represent directory in Linux

Tags: c, linux

In Linux we have 'mode' for each file/folder

if we do:

```
struct stat buf;
fstat("file_or_folder_name", &buf);
```

Then fstat function will fill the buf with lots of info including st_mode;

As I know this st_mode contains information about permission and the file type(tells if it is a file or a folder)

So I want to know If I have to generate/make/cook an st_mode from scratch, how can I make sure that it will tell it's 
a file and some other time it will tell that it is a folder? That type I will know by doing: S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)

ex:

```
mode_t my_file_mode = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH;
```

but that only tells about permission.
I want to make it to tell the file type also.

Also I have to fill other members of: struct stat
So what data I can assign to st_dev and st_ino etc any idea?

Actually the file does not exist on disk, I will be reading the objects from cloud, and I will tell the caller if its a file or a folder along with other info.

Comment: What do you mean by "file type" ?

Comment: Is it a file or a folder, looks like S_IFDIR can be added to list, I will have to test but still I don't know what to fill in st_dev and st_ino

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of `S_ISDIR`? It's platform specific, but you can just read it in the header.

Comment: Yes, you want `S_IFDIR` to indicate a directory: all of this is in the manpage. As for `st_dev` and `st_ino`, you don't have a device unless you're writing a driver, and the inode is probably meaningless but you can store something cloud-specific in there if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for S_IFMT

Its available in mode_t.

Predefined values are:

```
S_IFBLK       Block special.
S_IFCHR       Character special.
S_IFIFO       FIFO special.
S_IFREG       Regular.
S_IFDIR       Directory.
S_IFLNK       Symbolic link.
S_IFSOCK      Socket.
```

[Reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)

Comment: Yes but still I don't know what to fill in st_dev and st_ino

Comment: st_dev is the device identification. It basically identifies the device, through its major/minor number. This device hosts this file-system. Check out makedev [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/major). inode is a unique identifier assigned on "this" device. Why do you need to fill stat? I'd recommend refer [this](http://kukuruku.co/hub/nix/writing-a-file-system-in-linux-kernel) for a FS driver example.